# Why Ubuntu do not run video games? or some programs i used to run on windows 7

Tags: 13.04, compatibility

I cannot run video games I used to play in Windows 7, also there are a lot of programs that worked on Windows 7 but don't work on Ubuntu

Comment: Please post details of the specific games, as many *can* be played in linux.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu is an open sourced (free as in free beer and free speach) operating system built on the Debian Linux kernel.  Windows is built on the Microsoft proprietary NT kernel.  The methods of programming are different for the separate kernels.  This is a very basic description of why the programs are not usually cross compatible.

There is light at the end of the tunnel.  You can attempt to use WINE which translates in the backend for you.  You can read more on that on this site:

http://www.winehq.org/

Comment: For running Windows games on Linux, you may have more success with CrossOver than Wine: http://www.codeweavers.com/products/cxgames/ P.S.: CrossOver is not free.

Answer (score 0):

try installing wine WINE from Ubuntu Software Centre

but before you do that, check out this link which shows working programs on WINE

http://www.winehq.org/